# Graph with small max values on axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to make this graph of the two lines in Latex but for some reason the limits to the axis default to 1 immediately. I think it has something to do with how small my limits are but I'm not too sure.

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \begin{axis}[
        clip mode=individual, 
        enlargelimits=false, grid=major,  xmax=0.000001,
        axis on top=false, ymax=1.2*0.001,
        xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$
        ]

    \coordinate (a) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (axis cs:0.000001,1.1*0.001);
    \draw[thick] (a) -- (b);

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot Do you have any idea on how to do that? Can I have the range as [0,1] and put by hand the x10^(-6)?

Comment: @percusse's answer is much better than my proposal. (You can put whatever with e.g. `extra description/.code={\node[anchor=north] (description1) at (0.9,-0.1) {$\times 10^{-6}$};}` but there is really no need for that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not plotting but using TikZ directives. Plot the functions instead suchthat the axes can be automatically adjusted.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false, grid=major,  ymax=1.2e-3,
    axis on top=false,xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,no marks,domain=0:1e-6
    ]
    \addplot+[samples=3] {1100*x};
    \addplot+[samples=3] {100*x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]